# Users folder are Empty on harddrive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, user

I took this hard drive out of a dying computer ran HD tune test on it and it said the Hard drive was still good

We have a new PC that we are going to transfer the data to but when i looked into the old PC's hard drive the users folder was empty

[image]

[image]

I checked in the Windows,Windows.old and Temp and there is nothing in those either

The hard drive did have a Recovery drive but it said it was last modified in 2014

[image]

The question is where did the users data go? and is it possible to recover the user data?
**Update:**
I managed to recover the user Data with the data recovery tool 
i don't understand how the user data could disappear but oh well!

Comment: To clarify, did you actually try to open a folder within the `Users` hierarchy?  For example, `C:\Users\Public`.  Typically, a Windows operating system on an NTFS drive may *seem* like the folder is empty until you attempt to open it.  Then, a UAC prompt will appear and after you acknowledge it, you will have sufficient privileges to see the data within that folder.

Comment: Look in Windows.old it appears like they installed Windows over Windows at some point.  It’s also possible when that happened they choose not to keep their user data.  If that happen then the data is lost forever

Comment: @Run5k just gave it a shot it just said that folder dosnt exist.
Ramhound The windows.old folder is completely empty.
i do have hidden items visible but would files still be hidden?

Comment: I've decided to run easeUS on the hard drive to see if i can recover any data from it.